# HSQLDB update field of one table from field of another one

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, hsqldb

Trying to do this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET cost = t2.price
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t1.item_id = t2.item_id
```

It's working on PostgreSQL but not working on HSQLDB.

How to fix this script to support working both on PostgreSQL and HSQLDB?

Answer (score 5):

The `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax is non-standard. This is Standard SQL and works in HSQLDB (and apparently in PostgreSQL). I am really surprised that PostgreSQL 9.4 syntax documentation does not mention this syntax which has been in the Standard since 1992.

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET cost = (SELCT t2.price
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t1.item_id = t2.item_id)
```

Comment: Postgres _does_ support that syntax. The join is usually faster though

Comment: Good, but it is not in syntax doc http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/sql-update.html and the compatibility section at the end of the page has an example of this saying not implemented.

Comment: The multi column update `set (a,b) = (select x, y ...)` is not implemented. A **single** column update using a scalar sub select *is* supported: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d7929/1

Comment: They should document it. Edited the answer.

Comment: that not working. UPDATE table1 
SET cost = (SELECT price
FROM table2
WHERE table1.item_id = table2.item_id) works

Answer (score 3):

HSQLDB does not support `UPDATE ... FROM` statements. On HSQLDB use the [MERGE statement](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_merge_statement) instead. Out of my head, hoping this does not contain syntax errors:

```
 MERGE INTO table1 USING table2 ON table1.item_id = table2.item_id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET table1.cost = table2.price
```

Unfortunately, as of today postgres does not seem to support the [MERGE statement](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL_MERGE), but only the similar UPSERT.